# How to Install rsyslog v8.15 on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsyslog

Im trying to upgrade rsyslog 5.8.10 on Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09 to v8.15.

Here is my steps:

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/rsyslog.repo

```
[rsyslog_v8]  
name=Adiscon CentOS-$releasever - local packages for $basearch  
baseurl=http://rpms.adiscon.com/v8-stable/epel-7/$basearch  
enabled=0  
gpgcheck=0  
gpgkey=http://rpms.adiscon.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-Adiscon  
protect=1
```

sudo yum install rsyslog --enablerepo=rsyslog_v8 --setopt=rsyslog_v8.priority=1

### My Error output:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                           | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                        | 2.3 kB     00:00
rsyslog_v8/x86_64                                                                                                                                          | 2.5 kB     00:00
zabbix                                                                                                                                                     |  951 B     00:00
5 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:5.8.10-9.26.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.15.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_38)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_201)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_183)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgt for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-id128.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblogging-stdlog.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjson-c.so.2()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgthttp.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtbase.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libestr.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package json-c.x86_64 0:0.11-6.8.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libestr.x86_64 0:0.1.10-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libgt.x86_64 0:0.3.11-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package liblogging.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.15.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_38)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_201)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_183)(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-journal.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-id128.so.0()(64bit) for package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64 (rsyslog_v8)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64 (rsyslog_v8)
           Requires: libsystemd-id128.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64 (rsyslog_v8)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_201)(64bit)
Error: Package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64 (rsyslog_v8)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_38)(64bit)
Error: Package: rsyslog-8.15.0-1.el7.x86_64 (rsyslog_v8)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_183)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Instead of copy and paste your error message here, try read the error message. The error said that are missing dependecies and show two ways to fix.

Comment: I had to stick to version 8.13 to get it installing on Amazon linux with "sudo yum -y install rsyslog-8.13.0 --exclude=libksi1"

Comment: I have found a solution:

Answer (score 5):

Here is my step i have found working:

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/rsyslog.repo

```
[v8-stable]
name=Adiscon CentOS-6 - local packages for \$basearch
baseurl=http://rpms.adiscon.com/v8-stable/epel-6/\$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=http://rpms.adiscon.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-Adiscon
protect=1
```

Comment: Someone coming here, command to be used with above: "sudo yum install rsyslog --enablerepo=v8-stable --setopt=v8-stable.priority=1"

Answer (score 3):

To be able to install rsyslog 8 on Amazon linux instance, You need to enable the repo by setting 'enable=1'. The following are the steps that worked with me:

1. create a file 'rsyslog.repo' in /etc/yum.repos.d/
2. Put the following in the newly created file:

   > [v8-stable]
   >   name=Adiscon CentOS-6 - local packages for \$basearch
   >   baseurl=http://rpms.adiscon.com/v8-stable/epel-6/\$basearch
   >   enabled=1
   >   gpgcheck=0
   >   gpgkey=http://rpms.adiscon.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-Adiscon
   >   protect=1
3. Type the following command if you are upgrading rsyslog

   > yum upgrade rsyslog --disablerepo=amzn-main

   and the following command if you are installing rsyslog

   > yum install rsyslog --disablerepo=amzn-main